# Custom shipping method per product

Tags: magento-2.1

I have certain products that we can only deliver in our local city. All our other products can be distributed throughout the entire country. When you go to checkout in our store you’ll see the option to deliver locally, and the option to deliver throughout the country.

Now I want to make the “deliver throughout the county” invisible for the products that aren’t allowed to be shipped outside our city. Is there a way to do this? Can I set certain shipping methods only for certain products?

I really hope someone can help me out.

Thank you,

Etienne